# Create boolean mask on TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Suppose I have a list

```
x = [0, 1, 3, 5]
```

And I want to get a tensor with dimensions

```
s = (10, 7)
```

Such that the first column of the rows with indexes defined in `x` are 1, and 0 otherwise.

For this particular example, I want to obtain the tensor containing:

```
T = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Using numpy, this would be the equivalent:

```
t = np.zeros(s)
t[x, 0] = 1
```

I found this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128104/tensorflow-creating-mask-of-varied-lengths), but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

indices = tf.constant([[0, 1],[3, 5]], dtype=tf.int64)
values = tf.constant([1, 1])
s = (10, 7)

st = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, s)
st_ordered = tf.sparse_reorder(st)
result = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(st_ordered)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result)
```

Here is the output:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I slightly modified your indexes so you can see the `x,y` format of the indices

To obtain what you originally asked, set:

```
indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 0],[3, 0], [5, 0]], dtype=tf.int64)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can have dense_shape dynamically set? I have asked this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650464/tensorflow-sparsetensor-with-dynamically-set-dense-shape

Comment: Sure.  Posted an answer at the link you sent