# TensorFlow SparseTensor with dynamically set dense_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have previously asked this question [Create boolean mask on TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636319/create-boolean-mask-on-tensorflow) about how to get a tensor only with certain indices set to 1, and the rest of them to 0.

I thought the answer given by @MZHm would entirely solve my problem. Although, the argument `dense_shape` of `tf.SparseTensor` only accepts lists, and I want to pass a shape which is inferred from the graph (from the shape of another tensor which has variable shape). So in my case in specific, I want to do something like this:

```
# The tensor from which the shape of the sparse tensor is to be inferred
reference_t = tf.zeros([32, 50, 11])

# The indices that will be 1
indices = [[0, 0],
           [3, 0],
           [5, 0],
           [6, 0]]

# Just setting all the values for the sparse tensor to be 1
values = tf.ones([reference_t.shape[-1]])

# The 2d shape I want the sparse tensor to have
sparse_2d_shape = [reference_t.shape[-2],
                   reference_t.shape[-1]]

st = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, sparse_2d_shape)
```

From this I get the error:

> TypeError: Expected int64, got Dimension(50) of type 'Dimension'
>   instead.

How to I dynamically set the shape of a sparse tensor? Is there a better alternative to achieve what I'm aiming to do?

Comment: if the shape of `reference_t ` is fixed from the start, adding `.as_list()` to the `.shape` should do the job

Comment: It is not fixed from the start. The shape of reference_t itself is inferred from the shape of a 3d array that is given as input to a placeholder with shape [None, None, None]

Comment: then I think you should use the `tf.shape` function, as `shape_t = tf.shape(reference_t)`, and use it in place of `reference_t.shape`, and maybe you have to set `sparse_2d_shape` to a tensor as well, with a `tf.stack` or a `tf.concat`

Comment: My final objective from this is to then use `tf.tile` on the sparse tensor, so that the 1's will repeat along a third dimension (so that, in the end, the sparse tensor will have the same shape as `reference_t`). I think using `tf.zeros_like` could be a good alternative, but I have no idea about how I can set only specific slices of the zeros tensor to be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do to have a dynamic shape:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

indices = tf.constant([[0, 0],[1, 1]], dtype=tf.int64)
values = tf.constant([1, 1])
dynamic_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])
s = tf.shape(dynamic_input, out_type=tf.int64)

st = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, s)
st_ordered = tf.sparse_reorder(st)
result = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(st_ordered)

sess = tf.Session()
```

An input with (dynamic) shape `[5, 3]`:

```
sess.run(result, feed_dict={dynamic_input: np.zeros([5, 3])})
```

Will output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

An input with (dynamic) shape `[3, 3]`:

```
sess.run(result, feed_dict={dynamic_input: np.zeros([3, 3])})
```

Will output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

So there you go... dynamic sparse shape.

Comment: Great answer! About to give up after hours of trying to make sense of Tensorflow errors...... Thanks! :')