# TensorFlow SparseTensor with dynamically set indices, values and dense_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a tf.sparse.SpareTensor with dynamic size.

- The shape of `indices` is (?, 4)
- The shape of `values` is (?)
- The shape of `dense_shape` is (?, 1, 1, 200)

I want to run the following code:

```
sparse_tensor = tf.sparse_reorder(tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape))
```

The question mark (?) has the same value for each new tensor. This dimension represents the time (time series data).

Remark: I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650464/tensorflow-sparsetensor-with-dynamically-set-dense-shape) but in this case `indices` and `values` have fixed length.